# Is there a way to schedule a mail?

Tags: node.js, email, cron, nodemailer, schedule

I need to send emails every day and deliver them at a specific time.

Eg. I m calling the function at 1 am every day because no one uses the app at that time and I want emails to be delivered at 8 am the same day.

How can I achieve this by using nodemailer SMTP ?

Comment: You need to use a cron job

Comment: @DennisKozevnikoff I do use node cron to call a function every morning. But i need to send mails at different time during a day

Comment: @JakubBednár It's based on use cases. Myside I have a scenario like need to generate PDF at 8.35 AM and need to send email with attachment at 8.40 AM. So I have implement this two scenario in two different functions and with the help of node-cron I have been generating the pdf and sending it by mail